# How to make recent post on particular label for blogger ? I have added code check if it changes are work or not?

Tags: javascript, blogger

I have currently use this code if anyone change this code and make recent post on by label !!

I have used in my both sites

https://pohax.blogspot.com

I got the got in helplogger

If anyone change below script as recent post by label

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
 function showlatestpostswiththumbs(t){document.write('<ul           
  class="recent-posts-container">');for(var e=0;e<posts_no;e++){var  
      r,n=t.feed.entry[e],i=n.title.$t;if(e==t.feed.entry.length)break;for(var 
    o=0;o<n.link.length;o++)
  {if("replies"==n.link[o].rel&&"text/html"==n.link[o].type)var
    l=n.link[o].title,m=n.link[o].href;if("alternate"==n.link[o].rel)
   {r=n.link[o].href;break}}var u;try{u=n.media$thumbnail.url}catch(h)
  {s=n.content.$t,a=s.indexOf(" 
<img"),b=s.indexOf('src="',a),c=s.indexOf('"',b+5),d=s.substr(b+5,c-b-
 5),u=-1!=a&&-1!=b&&-1!=c&&""!=d?d:"https://2.bp.blogspot.com/-
  C3Mo0iKKiSw/VGdK808U7rI/AAAAAAAAAmI/W7Ae_dsEVAE/s1600/no-thumb.png"}var  
  p=n.published.$t,f=p.substring(0,4),g=p.substring(5,7),v=p.substring(8,10),
 w=new      
  Array;if(w[1]="Jan",w[2]="Feb",w[3]="Mar",w[4]="Apr",w[5]="May",w[6]="Jun",
w[7]="Jul",w[8]="Aug",w[9]="Sep",w[10]="Oct",w[11]="Nov",w[12]="Dec",docume
nt.write('<li class="recent-posts-

 list">'),1==showpoststhumbs&&document.write('<a href="'+r+'"><img 
   class="recent-post-thumb" src="'+u+'"/></a>'),document.write('<div  
   class="recent-post-title"><a href="'+r+'" target ="_top">'+i+"</a>
   </div>"),"content"in n)var A=n.content.$t;else if("summary"in n)var       
  A=n.summary.$t;else var A="";var    
 k=/<\S[^>]*>/g;if(A=A.replace(k,""),1==post_summary)
  if(A.length<summary_cha
   rs)document.write(A);else{A=A.substring(0,summary_chars);var 
  y=A.lastIndexOf(" ");A=A.substring(0,y),document.write(A+"...")}var 
 _="",$=0;document.write('<br><div class="recent-posts-   
 details">'),1==posts_date&&(_=_+w[parseInt(g,10)]+" "+v+" 
  "+f,$=1),1==readmorelink&&(1==$&&(_+=" | "),_=_+'<a href="'+r+'" 
 class="url" target ="_top">Read more</a>',$=1),1==showcommentslink&&
  (1==$&&(_+=" <br> "),"1 Comments"==l&&(l="1 Comment"),"0  
   Comments"==l&&
  (l="No      Comments"),l='<a href="'+m+'" target ="_top">'+l+"      
    </a>",_+=l,$=1),document.write(_),document.write(" 
 </div>"),document.write("
 </li>")}document.write("</ul>")}
 </script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
 var posts_no = 5;
 var showpoststhumbs = true;
 var readmorelink = true;
 var showcommentslink = true;
 var posts_date = true;
 var post_summary = true;
 var summary_chars = 40;</script>
 <script src="/feeds/posts/default?orderby=published&alt=json-in-     
 script&callback=showlatestpostswiththumbs"></script>
 <noscript>Your browser does not support JavaScript!</noscript>
 <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald'      
 rel='stylesheet'      type='text/css'/>
 <style type="text/css">
 img.recent-post-     
 thumb{padding:2px;width:65px;height:65px;float:left;margin:0px 10px 
  10px;border: 1px solid #69B7E2;}
 .recent-posts-container {font-family:'Oswald', sans-serif;font-
 size:12px;}
  ul.recent-posts-container li{list-style-type: none; margin-bottom:
  10px;font-size:12px;float:left;width:100%}
 ul.recent-posts-container {counter-reset: countposts;list-style-     
 type:none;padding:0;}
  ul.recent-posts-container li:before {content: 
  counter(countposts,decimal);counter-increment: countposts;z-index: 
   1;position:absolute; left: 0px; font-size: 13px;font-weight: 
   bold;color:
  #fff;background: #69B7E2;line- 
  height:25px;height:25px;width:25px;text-     align:center;-webkit-
  border-
  radius: 50%;-moz-border-radius: 50%;border-     radius: 50%;}
 .recent-posts-container a{text-decoration:none;}
 .recent-post-title {margin-bottom:5px;}
 .recent-post-title a {font-size:12px; text-transform: uppercase;           
  color:     
  #2aace3;}
 .recent-posts-details {margin: 5px 0px 0px 92px;font-size:11px;}
 .recent-posts-details a{color: #777;}
 </style>
```

I will change something codes but no one us working.please change this script is recent post by label.then instructed me how can I install were label name something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to change the feed URL to fetch recent posts from a particular label. The URL will be of the type -

```
http://www.blogname.blogspot.com/feeds/posts/default/-/[label]
```

The line that will need to be changed in the above code is -

```
<script src="/feeds/posts/default/-/[label]?orderby=published&alt=json-in-script&callback=showlatestpostswiththumbs"></script>
```

Replace `[label]` with the actual label name from which you want the recent posts to be fetched.

Comment: Thank You Lets I will try it

Answer (score 0):

Finally Igot above answer will eork